# Медленно открывается фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment

В приложении есть 5 кнопок внизу(своя реализация табов), каждая из них добавляет свой фрагмент в контейнер активити таким кодом:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new SomeFragment())
                        .commit();
```

Когда пользователь только запустил приложение и хочет перейти на фрагмент с гугл картой, к примеру, приложение медлит и через секунду-полторы фрагмент показывается.

В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: возможно, у вас есть какая-то дополнительная тяжеловесная инициализация во второстепенном потоке?

Comment: @metalurgus, вроде как нету. но тормозит почему-то. допусти открыт один фрагмент, нажимаешь на таб, я еще сеунду вижу первый фрагмент и потом только второй.

Comment: Может покажете код фрагмента, который медленно открывается?

Comment: @metalurgus все медленно открываются) даже просто с пустым OnCreateView.

Comment: @metalurgus я вот думаю, может как-то при запуске(сплешскрине) инициализировать их ?

Comment: @metalurgus, кстати, когда фрагмент один раз уже был открыт - если на него опять переключатся тогда все мгновенно. Если Вам нужна еще какая-то информация - напишите

Comment: Не получилось решить данную проблему?

Comment: @nonews нет (((

Comment: @researcher  я решил проблему, добавим в приложение сплеш-скрин.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594571/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: @researcher думаю этот вариант должен помочь