# Фрагмент стартует с задержкой

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет!
Пишу приложение на фрагментах, с `MVP` от `Moxy`.
В реализации только одна активити, которая является контейнером для всех фрагментов.

При старте приложения, показывается фрагмент со сплеш-скрином:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        showSplashFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void showSplashFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.ltContainer, SplashFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }
```

Суть проблемы в том, что фрагмент появляется только спустя пол-секунды.
До этого показывается просто белый экран.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

UPD:
**SlpashFragment**

```
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_splash;
    //@formatter:off
    @InjectPresenter SplashPresenter splashPresenter;
    @BindView(R.id.tvTimeCounter) TextView tvTimeCounter;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar progressBar;
    //@formatter:on
    public static SplashFragment newInstance() {
        SplashFragment fragment = new SplashFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        showSplashProgress();
        splashPresenter.showFragment();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void showSplashProgress() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void showAuthFragment() {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showAuthFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void showMapFragment() {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showMapFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void showReplayError() {
        // TODO: 22.11.2016
    }
}
```

Comment: В конце метода `showSplashFragment()` добавьте запись в лог. Эта запись будет выводиться без задержки?

Comment: да, запись чуть-чуть раньше появляется.Сейчас выложу код сплеша

Comment: Покажите `SplashPresenter`.

Comment: Через час буду у компьютера, выложу. Там идет проверка на содержимое SharedPreference и стартует асинхронный запрос в сеть.

Comment: Такая же проблема была и до использования презентера, кстати

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что сплеш скрин и должен показываться в этот момент, когда экран белый. В этот момент идет "холодный" запуск приложения. Картинку в сплеш скрине нужно задавать в теме. Подробнее прочитайте на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/312516/)

Comment: спасибо. Всё отлично!